# Mongo query output transformation/extraction via aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider my scenario where I need to get unique values for one of my collection's field.

I have document like:

```
_id:1
service: "microservice-1"
domain: "retail"

_id:2
service: "microservice-2"
domain: "insurance"

_id:3
service: "microservice-1"
domain: "retail"

_id:4
service: "microservice-3"
domain: "communications"

_id:5
service: "microservice-2"
domain: "insurance"
```

**Actual:**

Hence I am going with this query - `db.collections.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, listOfService: {"$addToSet" : "$service}}}])`
and I am getting output as `[microservice-1 microservice-2 microservice-3]` always.

**Expected:**
Instead of getting output as array of strings separated by empty space, I am expecting as below

```
microservice-1

microservice-2

microservice-3
```

I tried with $unwind function to extract but I am not able to do the same. Hence I need assistance on this as I am new to mongo.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want here. When you show the text such as "microservice-1" on three separate lines, does that mean you're looking to get back three separate documents? It's not possible for a client to receive only string information from the database without being inside of a document(s). Each document will contain at least one field name and it's e corresponding value. Of course the client (including the shell) can be configured to display that information in whatever way is desired

Answer (score 0):

From the above mentioned expected output, it is clear that you wants all unique services as:

microservice-1

microservice-2

microservice-3

Because above there in sample collection multiple time these services are mentioned.
So, grouping on service will give the expected result, and as mongodb store data in json format so result got also in json format.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":"$service"}},{$project:{"_id":0, "service":"$_id"}}])
```

There are only two possible way to view data, as a json or array in some field name